# fold expression and function name lookup

Tags: c++, c++17, clang, compiler-bug

I am learning fold expressions in C++17. I have the following code

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

namespace io {
template<typename T>
std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &in, std::vector<T> &vec) {
  for (auto &x : vec)
    in >> x;
  return in;
}

template<class... Args> void scan(Args &... args) {
  (std::cin >> ... >> args);
}
}// namespace io

int main() {
    std::vector<int> s(1), t(1);
    io::scan(s, t);
    std::cout << s[0] << ' ' << t[0] << '\n';
}
```

Using [GCC 9.3.0](https://wandbox.org/permlink/HxCd8zcnwIuq6bpR), the code compiles and runs correctly, but using [Clang 10.0.0](https://godbolt.org/z/wTMzhU), the same code does not compile:

```
<source>:13:16: error: call to function 'operator>>' that is neither visible in the template definition nor found by argument-dependent lookup
  (std::cin >> ... >> args);
               ^
<source>:19:9: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'io::scan<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >' requested here
    io::scan(s, t);
        ^
<source>:6:15: note: 'operator>>' should be declared prior to the call site
std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &in, std::vector<T> &vec) {
              ^
1 error generated.
```

Why clang rejets the code but gcc accepts it?

Comment: Some time has passed since this post, but seemed related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45569698/clang-cant-find-template-binary-operator-in-fold-expression?rq=1. clang was behind gcc with fold expressions.

Comment: @user176692 Thanks for the information. I tried to compile code form that post with clang 10.0.0, and got a similar error https://godbolt.org/z/st-oNo. I'll mark this question a duplicate some time later.

Comment: If you need a replacement, use `((std::cin >> args), ...);`. This syntax is not bugged in Clang.

Comment: @user176692 It is claimed that Clang 5 and later implement all the features of C++17 https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html#cxx17 I think this might be a bug of Clang.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a Clang bug. Clang versions 11 and earlier did not properly implement two-phase name lookup for the operator in a fold expression, and would incorrectly perform the first-phase lookup from the lexical scope in which the instantiation of the fold-expression happened to be performed rather than doing the first-phase lookup from the context of the template definition.

I [fixed this](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/commit/ed5a18fc0399dce994aa354a33e6f981f9828647) relatively recently (unfortunately not in time for the upcoming Clang 11 release), and the test case is now [accepted by Clang trunk](https://godbolt.org/z/sboK3P).

Comment: Now I can finally close *one* of these as a duplicate…